# Xamarin Grid View empty cells

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, gridview, frontend

I have a grid view that contains some image buttons. In this case however, I would like to have some of the cells as empty without it shifting the position. Here is an image of what I am trying to do:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/9fzjT2C.png]

As you can see, I don't need the corner buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the alpha of the button to 0 made it invisible:

[image]